# Texture doesn't show up

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a model, with a node setup that includes a texture. The problem is that the texture isn't showing.

*How it should look (the little spot distortions are visible):*

[image]

*How it looks:*

[image]

*My node setup*

### Node Setup

[image]

The file can be downloaded here: https://mega.nz/#!N1hkWQKT!bKLTkcQFxjCWtEtSZgEdV89VmERzoF-ui3EmUqpWxCg

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it

Comment: When uploading files please make sure that your textures are packed, this one is missing the very texture you ask about...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would do much better using an image (or even a *Noise Texture*) as a fac between two orange *Diffuse BSDF* shaders (one dark and one light). Your texture is applying perfectly, it's just that plugging it into the *Roughness:* value of a *Glossy BSDF* doesn't do much.

*Proposed node setup and viewport render:*

[image]

Here is an alternate .blend file with only the node setup (the original was too big for Blend Exchange):

https://mega.nz/#!pcZAlTTI!zmL45Z9Jqw83DvPEwiNk3gnmMItPE8SlrYYcL8MCteg

**Edit:**

I believe that the *Noise Texture* and above image does still create a better result, but using the *Image Texture*, I created the following.

[image]

I turned the *Mapping* node's *Scale:* value way down to *0.05* so that you can see the *Image Texture* from the viewport's distance to the bear. If you have it at *2*, the following is a zoomed in bear. That to the left; that's his right eye.

[image]

Comment: @cegaton perhaps, but the op didn't include the image in the .blend file. I might still have included this, but I had no way to use the image without actually being able to see it.

Comment: It is usefull, but, why the noise texture only apears in the head?

Comment: @Jagredom I wouldn't know. It could be in the mapping. I am not quite sure exactly how you made the .blend file, but I figured you'd probably be able to reapply some materials and figure it out. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. Next time I will pack them

Comment: I'll pack again the file, so the question can be answered correctly

Comment: @Jagredom I edited with the answer. Please consider reaccepting my answer if the edited or original node setup helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The image texture is set to non-color data , it should be set to color-data if this is your texture.

The output of the color ramp should be connected to the diffuse shader and not the glossy,also right now the color ramp is connected to the roughness of the shader,it should be connected to color.

Comment: What type of unwrap should I use for the full body?

Comment: sorry i didn't download the blend file to know what the topology is like, it seems easy enough to unwrap it by marking some seams and using smart uv project.