# How to create spots that appear in material in Cycles?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I want to create a **spots** map for any material, so it looks like this:

[image]

*Aprreciate the little spots on the front*

Comment: Are you talking about the spots that can be seen in the eyes ?

Comment: I think he means the three spots in the cheeks/wiskers. Short answers is I don't think you can easily do it with nodes alone. Either use a specific image texture dor it or you are probably better off modeling them with actual geometry

Comment: Yes, I mean that

Comment: What did my answer to [Texture doesn't show up](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55374/texture-doesnt-show-up/55398#55398) not explain? This looks like a question that would have the exact same answer. However, if you are looking for something that would apply that effect to __every__ material, I can show you how to do that. Let me know.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Comment: PD: In this question I ask for spots textures and how to create them

Comment: @Jagredom Please put a bit more effort into your questions and state clearly what you are looking for.

Comment: I feel as if this is a simple case of just creating some UV spheres (Or whatever sphere floats your boat) and making them black.

Comment: The problem is that in the material preview, it appears as it should look, but in the model don't

Comment: @Jagredom Posted my answer. Let me know if you need any more info. Lastly, if it helps, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Judging by the reflections visible on those spots, I suspect they are actual geometry in the pictured model (*maybe* they are normal mapped, but I don't see any potential evidence of a normal map anywhere else)

Comment: @gandalf3 Could you be more specific? I cannot see any reflections in __Img 5__. I did not bump map the texture, and I don't _believe_ that they are surface deformities. Plus, the OP set the _Glossy BSDF's Roughness:_ value to 1.

Comment: @shadyPuck to what spots are you referring to?
 I thought the op meant the three black spots on the cheeks

Comment: @gandalf3 OH! No, I was referring to the roughly _Noise Texture_ish spots that vary the surface color. See my comment above w/ 3 up votes and Jagredom's reply. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The material appears in the Preview panel, but not in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the node setup from **Img 2** to that from **Img 1** (which represents any basic material [*Main Body Th3Unkn0wns* shown in all example screenshots]) to create the nodes from **Img 3**, which should change the base material preview from **Img 4** to the spotted one from **Img 5**. Note that I will be using the *Noise Texture* setup from [Texture doesn't show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55374/texture-doesnt-show-up/55398#55398), but you can easily substitute the one with the *Image Texture*. Also, I will be modifying the face material in this case, but as I said, the method will work for anything and everything. Lastly, you may have to fiddle with the *Noise Texture's Scale:* value to get it to look right for each case.

*Img 1:*

[image]

*Img 2:*

[image]

*Img 3:*

[image]

*Img 4:*

[image]

*Img 5:*

[image]

*A quick word about using the node setup:*

The nodes from **Img 2** will always go directly after the last shader and before the *Material Output*. The added *Diffuse BSDF* shader is pure black. I chose a *0.8 Fac:* value in the added *Mix Shader* because it distorted the other shader to a dark enough value to see the surface irregularities. If you want to use an *Image Texture*, simply swap it out with the *Noise Texture*. You may also want to change an *Image Texture's Texture Coordinates* from *Generated* to *UV*, but you might not.